# how to do large batch insert in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, large-data, batch-insert

I am trying to insert 100000 rows to database.
I am using insert_batch function.

I can insert upto 80000 rows but when I create more than that it will throw a HTTP ERROR 500 error.

what should I do? I am new to programming. thankyou.

this is my code;

### controller

```
            if ($validation_result) {
                $serial_numbers  = $this->serial_numbers_model->generate_serial_numbers($product_id, $partner_id, $serial_number_quantity, $serial_number_start);

                $issued_date     = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $inserted_rows   = 0;

                foreach ($serial_numbers as $sn) {

                    $check_number = $this->serial_numbers_model->generate_check_number();

                    $first_serial_number = reset($serial_numbers);
                    $last_serial_number = end($serial_numbers);
                    $inserted_rows++;

                    $insert_data[] = array(
                        'partner_id'            => $partner_id,
                        'product_id'            => $product_id,
                        'check_number'          => $check_number,
                        'serial_number'         => $sn,
                        'issued_time'           => $issued_date,
                        'serial_number_status'  => CREATE_STATUS
                    );
                }

                $this->serial_numbers_model->insert_batch($insert_data);

                $all_rows_count  = $this->db->count_all_results('serial_numbers', FALSE);
                $views_data['serial_number_min_max'] = $this->get_serial_number_min_max();
                $views_data['status_counts'] = $this->get_status_counts();
                $views_data['success_msg'] = sprintf('発行完了しました. 合計件数 (%s)  | 発行件数 (%s) => %sから%sまで', $all_rows_count, $inserted_rows, $first_serial_number, $last_serial_number);
            }
```

### model

```
public function insert_batch($set_data)
{
    if (!empty($set_data)) {
        $chunk_array = array_chunk($set_data, 1000);

        $this->db->trans_start();
        foreach ($chunk_array as $key => $data) {
            $this->db->insert_batch($this->table, $data);
        }
        $this->db->trans_complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your error log say?

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi oh it saysPHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /var/www/html/application/controllers/admin/serial_numbers.php on line 192, referer: http://localhost:60080/admin/serial_numbers/add